# Select array values based on another array

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays :  “Array-List” and “Array-Criteria” :

```
Array-List
(
    [1] => APPLE
    [2] => BANANA
    [3] => ORANGE
    [4] => LEMON
)

Array-Criteria
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

Is there a quick way (my `Array-List` can consist of thousands of entries) to select the values from `Array-List` based on `Array-Criteria` without looping through `Array-List` in PHP?

Comment: What is the expected result? Have you had a look at `array_filter`?

Comment: `$arrayList[$arrayCriteria[1]]` => "Orange" - Is that what you mean? If not: How is criteria else connected to the list?

Comment: What is `$arrayCriteria`?

Comment: what are you actually looking for? Select what values? How do the arrays link up?

Comment: If it would be SQL, it would be SELECT value FROM Array-List WHERE key IN (SELECT value FROM Array-Criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_intersect_key` and `array_flip` functions to get data as:

```
$arr1 = Array-List
(
    [1] => APPLE
    [2] => BANANA
    [3] => ORANGE
    [4] => LEMON
)

$arr2 = Array-Criteria
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)



var_dump(array_intersect_key($arr1, array_flip($arr2)));
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. This was exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

If you loop over the criteria, you can build a list of the macthing items...

```
$selected = [];
foreach ( $arrayCriteria as $element ) {
    $selected[] = $arrayList[$element];
}
```

Then `$selected` will be a list of the items your after.

Also in a quick test, it's about twice as fast as using the `array_` methods.

Comment: True, but it's still a loop involved. I think Gufran Hasan's solution is slicker.

Comment: Not disagreeing with the other answer being good, but any solution will involve a loop.

Comment: I did some speed tests and array_intersect_key solution seems to be the fastest.

Comment: Difficult to know as it's all affected by the number of entries etc.  But as I said, I tried it and found this to take 1/2 the time in my tests.