# Select a value from an array based on another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, `percentiles` and `percentile_bounds` and another int value `total_score`. Given the total score, I want to return the percentile in which this value is. Ie. I want to return a value from `percentiles` which corresponds to placing the `total_score` within the `percentile_bounds`. In python, I would do:

```py
import numpy as np

percentiles = np.array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95])
percentile_bounds = np.array([ 84, 104, 109, 115, 120, 123, 125, 127, 129, 132, 135, 136, 137, 139, 141, 145, 148, 151, 155, 159])

# example 1
total_score = 130
print(percentiles[np.where(percentile_bounds==(percentile_bounds[percentile_bounds<total_score][-1]))])
# 40

# example 2
total_score = 153
print(percentiles[np.where(percentile_bounds==(percentile_bounds[percentile_bounds<total_score][-1]))])
# 85

# example 3
total_score = 100
print(percentiles[np.where(percentile_bounds==(percentile_bounds[percentile_bounds<total_score][-1]))])
# 0
```

and I found a way in PHP (function sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193726/remove-array-elements-that-are-less-than-x), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959222/get-the-index-of-a-certain-value-in-an-array-in-php)) but it is very clumsy and long:

```php
<?php
// Example 4
$total_score = 120;

$percentile_bounds = [84, 104, 109, 115, 120, 123, 125, 127, 129, 132, 135, 136, 137,139, 141, 145, 148, 151, 155, 159];
       
$percentiles = [0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95];

// get the last element from percentile_bounds which is less than total_score
$value = end(array_filter($percentile_bounds, function ($x) use ($total_score) { return $x < $total_score; }));

// find its index
$key = array_search($value, $percentile_bounds);

// find the corresponding value in percentiles
echo "percentile: $percentiles[$key]";
// 15
```

Is there a better way of selecting the element from one array (`percentiles`) based on a position of an element (`total_score`) in the other array (`percentile_bounds`)?

Thanks

Note: it is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743164/select-array-values-based-on-another-array).

Clarification: For `total_score<=84` the result should be 0 (based on how percentiles work) but it also should not happen. In the code above I do not deal with this condition so it's ok not to but if the solution does, the better :). Thanks @jspit for pointing it out!

Comment: Why is this two arrays to begin with, why not one array that uses 0, 5, 10 etc. as _keys_?

Comment: I guess that's just because I think in python and not PHP :D. I have data, then from them, I get the percentiles and the bounds which are two different arrays, then I go back to PHP (I do not have the data within PHP). I didn't think of it as a dictionary.

Comment: no result is defined for a total_score <= 84

Comment: @jspit, thanks, good point, in that case, it should be 0 (based on how percentiles work) but it also should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this line where `array_keys` gives us an array of keys of our filtered array. `end` and `max` do the same job in this case because we have a sorted array and want to return its last index. So finally `$percentiles[$lastIndexKeyOfOurFilteredArray]` is what we print out:

```php
echo $percentiles[max(array_keys(array_filter($percentile_bounds,function ($x) use ($total_score){return $x<$total_score; })))]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: what @nima writes is exactly what I would like to ask you. Could you please provide some explanations to your code? How it works, what it does etc., exactly as nima writes. Thanks

Comment: Sure, `array_keys` gives us array of keys of our filtered array. `end` and `max` do the same job in this case because we have sorted array and want to return its last index. So finally  `$percentiles[$lastIndexKeyOfOurFilteredArray]` is what we print out.

Comment: One more issue with this: if `array_keys` is empty (the value is less than any in the`percentile_bounds`), the `max` function fails. How can it be fixed? The expected behaviour is to return 0.

Comment: PHP max function will throw an E_WARNING error and return a boolean false because of empty array input. PHP internal type-casting conversion will convert the boolean false to integer 0 so you already have your expected 0. You can skip the warning with an "@" {echo @percentiles[max(arr...}. Obviously its just a trick for preserving single-line style of the code and its better to use if/else statement for validating data before passing to function to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` would be more readable and performant approach compared to `array_filter`

```
$total_score = 153;

$percentile_bounds = [84, 104, 109, 115, 120, 123, 125, 127, 129, 132, 135, 136, 137, 139, 141, 145, 148, 151, 155, 159];

$percentiles = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95];

foreach ($percentile_bounds as $key => $bound) {
    if ($bound >= $total_score) {
        echo 'percentile: ' . $percentiles[max(0, $key - 1)];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: echo "percentile: ".($key > 0 ? $percentiles[$key-1] : "??");

Comment: @jspit Good catch. thanks, buddy. we can use `max()` instead of ternary operator to resolve negative index

Comment: And I believe it's missing an equal sign: `if ($bound >= $total_score)` otherwise, the borders fall into the wrong interval. Also, would you have an explanation or reference for why it has better performance? Thanks

Comment: One  more thing, it fails for `$total_score>=160`